# Does crossing multiple sub-stat upgrade threshold at the same time force every bonus to be applied on the same sub-stat?

Tags: genshin-impact

When upgrading artifact pieces in Genshin Impact it is possible with some luck/planning to increase the level of an artifact by more than 8 levels at a time. Every 4 levels an artifact gets a boost to a random sub-stat OR a new sub-stat if it currently has less than 4. This means that an artifact that is boosted at least 8 levels from a single upgrade should apply two sub-stat upgrades at the same time. This in turn brings us to a question...

What happens when multiple sub-stat upgrades are applied at the same time? I think that new stats take precedence, but what about an artifact that already reached 4 sub-stats? The few times I saw this happening to players it looked like every increase was applied to the same stat instead that randomly for each upgrade as expected.

Basically it looks like increasing a 4 sub stat artifact all the way to level 8 should roll for a sub stat upgrade twice separately, but when level 4 and level 8 are reached at the same time what really happens is that the system rolls ONCE for a single stat to upgrade and then twice for each upgrade to apply.

Is this true? I doubt this can be abused anyway but it would still be a nice trivia to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a wrong assumption.

**I tested it with lvl 1 to 20 with 3 stats:**

[image: artifact_level_1]
[image: artifact_level_1_to_20]

Upgrades of substats done(lvl 4, 8, 12, 16, 20 = 5 upgrades):

- 2 upgrades: Elemental Mastery added + 1 Upgrade
- 2 upgrades: Energy recharge
- 1 upgrade: HP
- ATK got 0 upgrades

**And with 4 stats:**

[image]

Here, 4 different properties got upgraded and one didn't even recieve 1 upgrade as well.

I also tested lvl 3 to 8 with a 3 stat artifact, it got a new property and a upgrade to an existing one.

Comment: Then I guess that I have to thank RNG god for tricking me into believing the opposite. This is enough proof, thank you for the assistance.

Comment: This is correct. Once you've got 4 substats, every 4 levels upgrades one of them randomly. Note that the AMOUNT of each upgrade is also random. For example each time DEF is rolled it can increase by 16, 19, 21 or 23. This is also true for the initial substat roll. So the DEF on the Shaft of Remembrance in the last picture got the worst roll for it's initial value, but got the best roll for it's 2nd roll. Similarly ER can be 4.5, 5.2,5.8 or 6.5. etc. etc.

Check out [Genshin Optimizer](https://frzyc.github.io/genshin-optimizer) if you want to get a better understanding of artifacts.

Comment: @aslum oh, I got that part already. The only doubt I had was about the specific case I mentioned, mostly because I only saw "lucky" cases so far.